# how to create tar gz file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm searching for solution to solve problem with creating tar.gz archive using Powershell v4. I couldn't find extensions/packets created or verified by Microsoft to provide such functionality. Do such solutions exist [tar-ing and gzip-ing]?

Answer (score 24):

Another possibility is to call out to the native tar command that Windows now supports (with gzip compression):

```powershell
tar -cvzf filename.tgz mydir
```

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Containers/Tar-and-Curl-Come-to-Windows/ba-p/382409

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft implemented a [gzipstream in System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .Net 2.0 There are tons of examples in C# and many others in powershell. The [Powershell Community Extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) also have Write-Zip and Write-Tar functions. Here is a function for gzip I did quite a while back. It should really be updated to handle multiple inputs and better output naming. It also only handles one file at a time. But it should get you started if you want to see how its done.

```
function New-GZipArchive
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, 
                  PositionalBinding=$true)]
    [OutputType([Boolean])]
    Param
    (
        # The input file(s)
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [String]
        $fileIn,

        # The path to the requested output file
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        #validation is done in the script as the only real way to determine if it is a valid path is to try it
        [String]
        $fileOut,

        # Param3 help description
        [Switch]
        $Clobber
    )
    Process
    {
        if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess("$fileIn", "Zip file to $fileOut"))
        {
            if($fileIn -eq $fileOut){
                Write-Error "You can't zip a file into itself"
                return
            }
            if(Test-Path $fileOut){
                if($Clobber){
                    Remove-Item $fileOut -Force -Verbose
                }else{
                    Write-Error "The output file already exists and the Clobber parameter was not specified. Please input a non-existent filename or specify the Clobber parameter"
                    return
                }
            }
            try{
                #create read stream                
                $fsIn = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($fileIn, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read)
                #create out stream
                $fsOut = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($fileOut, [System.IO.FileMode]::CreateNew, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
                #create gzip stream using out file stream
                $gzStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GZipStream($fsout, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)
                #create a shared buffer
                $buffer = New-Object byte[](262144) #256KB
                do{
                    #read into buffer
                    $read = $fsIn.Read($buffer,0,262144)
                    #write buffer back out
                    $gzStream.Write($buffer,0,$read)
                }
                while($read -ne 0)
            }
            catch{
                #really should add better error handling
                throw
            }
            finally{
                #cleanup
                if($fsIn){
                    $fsIn.Close()
                    $fsIn.Dispose()
                }
                if($gzStream){
                    $gzStream.Close()
                    $gzStream.Dispose()
                }
                if($fsOut){
                    $fsOut.Close()
                    $fsOut.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dir *.txt | %{New-GZipArchive $_.FullName $_.FullName.Replace('.txt','.gz') -verbose -clobber}
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Zip file to C:\temp\a.gz" on Target "C:\temp\a.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Remove file" on Target "C:\temp\a.gz".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Zip file to C:\temp\b.gz" on Target "C:\temp\b.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Remove file" on Target "C:\temp\b.gz".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Zip file to C:\temp\c.gz" on Target "C:\temp\c.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Remove file" on Target "C:\temp\c.gz".
```

Comment: What about taring process?

Comment: Take a look at the powershell community extensions https://pscx.codeplex.com/ they have a write-tar script. I don't know of an easier way to do it as I have never needed to work with tar files on Windows.

Comment: Before I discovered the new `tar` command I tried Pscx, but it does not currently install cleanly on current PowerShell without this workaround: https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/issues/23#issuecomment-356272051,